# I possibly installed malware, help please

Tags: malware

I was looking for a Twitter app on Ubuntu Software Centre and I downloaded a fake Twitter app from snapcraft. Didn't notice and didn't read the comments before I hit install, like an idiot. The name was actually Twitterr, with two Rs, and comments reported it being fake and possibly malware. It doesn't show up anywhere upon installing. After I realized my mess up, I hit remove in the software centre. Am I ok now? How can I be sure I don't have any malware now? Is there something beyond just hitting remove in the software centre that I should do? Any help would be really appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Oh and I'm running Ubuntu MATE 20.4

Comment: In the software centre the app's source is snapcraft.io, and it's by Korbs Studio. It's 8.2 kb.

Comment: Where do you see that this may be malware? https://snapcraft.io/twitterr that is the site for the app.

Comment: Reviewers on the Ubuntu Software Center for Twitterr suggest that it is a fake app rather than necessarily malware which will harm your computer  and if you have removed it all should be ok. Others suggest that they can run it but it does seem to have poor reviews. Perhaps contact the developers Korbs Studio for re-assurances?

Comment: What makes snapcraft safe to install apps without having to worry about malware? Like how can I be sure that when I hit remove in the software centre that whatever fake app I downloaded is completely gone, and there aren't any malicious files anywhere on my laptop?

Comment: Like, it's weird the app disappears once installed, and can't be found anywhere. Even though I clicked remove through the software centre I still feel a bit sketched because of that.

Comment: @tmrrr You know, sometimes you have to log out and log back in before an app will show up in your installed applications.

Comment: It's not just me, the review comments for this app report the same problem. it appears to be a fake app. when you download it isn't anywhere to open. just want to make sure I haven't accidentally let something onto my computer . and that when I hit "remove" in the app store, everything I installed has really been removed

Comment: I ran the snap list command in the terminal and I don't see it listed so I guess it's gone. And a snap is sandboxed, so I don't need to worry about files other than that snap getting onto my computer through the snap install right? Thanks everyone for the help understanding. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

> └─$ snap search twitter
>
> Name                 Version               Publisher      Notes    Summary
>
> twitterr             2.03                  korbs          -        Twitter

Read the [trust and security of snap-store](https://snapcraft.io/blog/trust-and-security-in-the-snap-store). Snap-store is so safe area. And, look in Linux main developer doesn't provide everything for Linux. So, other programmers always try to build something for Linux. You can install whatever you wish from Snap-store. Don't worry.

Comment: That is the app I installed, yes. Thank you for the reassurance regarding downloading packages from snap. I got worried about it being potential malware because people in the review comments noted also how the app can't be located or opened once installed, and people were saying don't install, fake app, may be malware.

So if I removed it through the software centre interface whatever package I downloaded is definitely off my computer?

Comment: @tmrrr Yeah...!

Answer (score 2):

I would like to confirm this is not malware and is opened sourced.
The project was renamed to Twitterish: https://github.com/KorbsStudio/Twitterish

Anyway, the project is outdated and I've pulled it off of the Snap store, since I don't like outdated apps laying around.
I highly recommend to get Chirp instead, as it's basically the same thing.
https://github.com/hanford/chirp

Comment: +1 for your responsible message. thanks